# GHC uses catch-all instance if constraint is missing?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, overlapping-instances

I've been experimenting with this simple implementation of HLists and a function `hasInt` which returns `True` if an `Int` is a member of the list:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

data HNil = HNil
  deriving (Show, Read)

data HCons a b = HCons a b
  deriving (Show, Read)

class HasInt a where
  hasInt :: a -> Bool

instance HasInt HNil where
  hasInt _ = False

instance HasInt as => HasInt (HCons a as) where
  hasInt (HCons a as) =  (isInt a) || (hasInt as)

class IsInt a where
  isInt :: a -> Bool

instance IsInt Int where
  isInt _ = True

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} IsInt a where
  isInt _ = False

three = 3 :: Int

main = do
  putStrLn $ "isInt three = " ++ show (isInt three) -- True
  putStrLn $ "isInt True  = " ++ show (isInt True)  -- False
  print $ hasInt $ HCons three $ HCons True HNil    -- False ???
```

This doesn't give the expected results. However, it does seem to work if I change:

```
    instance HasInt as => HasInt (HCons a as) where
```

to:

```
    instance (IsInt a, HasInt as) => HasInt (HCons a as) where
```

On the other hand, I normally expect GHC to complain if I use a type class function but don't include the constraint, and I don't get any such indication in this case.

Clearly it has to do something with the catch-all instance `IsInt a`. I will get the `Could not deduce (IsInt a) arising from a use of 'isInt'`
error if I replace the catch-all instance with:

```
instance IsInt Bool where isInt _ = False
instance IsInt HNil where isInt _ = False
```

My question is: Is this expected behavior of GHC - that it will silently use a catch-all instance if there is no explicit type class constraint?

Comment: I don't see any `instance IsInt Int where isInt _ = True` here, which makes me very confused about how you get anything to return True ever.

Comment: Yes - I missed that line. Question updated.

Comment: This is one of the reasons overlapping instances are so horrible. If you leave out an instance, everything will compile and everything will be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is the expected behavior. If you write

```
instance Foo a
```

you are declaring that all types are instances of `Foo`, and GHC *believes* you.

This is 100% analogous to the following:

```
foo :: Int -> Bool
foo x = x > 0
```

Even though you don't have `Ord Int` in the context, GHC knows there is such an instance. Likewise, in:

```
bar :: a -> b
bar x = {- use the Foo instance for x here -}
```

Even though you don't have `Foo a` in the context, GHC knows there is such an instance.

Comment: I guess I understand, but the surprising thing is the code behaves differently depending on whether or not the constraint is present or not, and I don't get any indication from GHC either in the form of an error or warning that I might be in for a surprise.

Comment: @ErikR That's what you signed up for when you enabled `OverlappingInstances`, I'm afraid.